# hide function based on yes or no

Tags: hide, show

I'm currently using a script that hides rows if column M equals "Yes", but I want it to hide rows if column M equals "Yes" or "No". I tried

```
if(r[0] == "Yes","No")
```

but that hid all rows. Help?

```
function onOpen() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());

  s.getRange('M:M')
    .getValues()
    .forEach( function (r, i) {
    if (r[0] == 'YES') 
      s.hideRows(i + 1);
    });
}
```

I tried

```
function onOpen() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());

  s.getRange('M:M')
    .getValues()
    .forEach( function (r, i) {
    if (r[0] == 'YES') || if (r[0] =='No') 
      s.hideRows(i + 1);
    });
 }
```

But that only hid rows with "yes"

Comment: Did you try:

if(r[0] == "Yes") || if(r[0] == "No")

Comment: I tried that but I'm not sure I entered it correctly

Comment: My bad, try this: if ((r[0] == "Yes") || (r[0] == "No"))

Comment: Perfect, thank you!